# How to write Exponential distribution in overleaf

Tags: math-mode, cases

I am new to overleaf and having trouble in writing an exponential distribution function in overleaf.
[image: Exponential distribution]

Could anyone please help me share some insight on how to write it?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. You can use `cases` enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cases` (or `dcases`), and although I prefer writing `exp`, if you insist on using `e` ensure it is an upright letter, as its a number, not a variable, so use `\mathrm{e}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\lambda \exp(-\lambda x) & x > 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = 
\begin{dcases}
\lambda \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x} & x > 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Mathtools` is a package robust than `amsmath`. If you use `mathtools` only you have the same result. Obviously for `dcases` is necessary `mathtools`.